# Macro to delete emails from a sender

Tags: macros, automation, microsoft-outlook-2013

I get a lot of garbage email.  I'd like to create a macro (or something) that will work against a highlighted email and, when activated, does 2 things:

1. Create a rule for the sender to delete all future emails
2. Delete the current email

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

> > 1. Create a rule for the sender to delete all future emails

I think you can add the sender to Block List so that all future emails will be moved to Junk Folder.

If you still want to create rule, you can refer to following rule descriptions:

[image]

Regarding detailed steps, please check [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59).

> > 2. Delete the current email

In Outlook, we can also use Rules function in Home tab to move the messages from a same sender to the Deleted Items folder.

1. Please select the email whose sender you will remove emails by.
2. Click Home > Rules > Always Move Messages From, and your selected email['s sender has been added after the function. See screenshot:

[image]

3. Then a Rules and Alerts dialog box will display, and specify the Deleted Items folder to place the emails, and click the OK button.
4. All emails from the sender of selected email in the Inbox have been moved to the Deleted Items folder.

[image]

5. After removing the emails, please click Home > Rules > Manage Rules & Alerts, and then turn off or delete the new rule in the popping up Rules and Alerts dialog box. See screenshot:

[image]